# React Native - How to debug javascript code better?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using React Native 0.13. Currently I have an Android emulator in which I can preview the application. I work in OSX Yosemite. In a lot of cases nothing happens when I click on a button or link and it is due to some error in javascript, but I do not get any error message anywhere, so it becomes very hard to solve the problem. For console logging I use:

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

Which displays the console.log outputs, but it doesn't give me the exact errors when the code breaks.

Can someone suggest me a good way of debugging and how to get the error output to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to debug JS code is by using Chrome devtools. You can enter the mode when JS code is executed remotely in chrome tab, and then use normal chrome tools to do step through debugging. To do so you'd need to open react-native dev menu and select "debug in chrome" (see [this link for more detailed instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)). Then in chrome you can open dev console with `alt + ⌘ + j`, go to "sources" tab and use `⌘ + p` to navigate to some specific JS file. Then place breakpoints there etc...

If you want to debug java code, the easiest way is to have Android Studio launch your app. Then you can run your app with debugger attached (with `ctr + d`) or use "Attach debugger to Android process" button from the launch menu and selecting your running app from the menu. Then you can place breakpoints in Android Studio for the java code.

Comment: Thank you for an answer before. I have tried the debugging in Chrome, it kinda works, but my main problem still exists. For example let's say I type in javascript code like this: items.length() instead of items.length. The exception message that I get is "Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `.$scene_1`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used". This is completely unrelated to the error and it does not even tell me the line or in which file, which makes debugging a horrible experience.

Comment: In the case of the error you described it looks like you should get much better error description even with no debugging enabled (in a form of react native "redbox"). Would you be able to provide a simple app (js module) that would illustrate the issue and report this on github (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues). Thanks!